How to create CodeAnalysis analyzer for razor files?
I'm creating custom roslyn analyzers in order to enforce custom code style rules in my project. So far it's been going well with the help of AI generators for .cs files. However I cannot get an analyzer to work for .razor file. Here's what I have now:
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
    
    context.RegisterCompilationStartAction(compilationContext
        => compilationContext.RegisterSyntaxTreeAction(AnalyzeRazorFile));
}


private void AnalyzeRazorFile(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context)
{
    if (!context.Tree.FilePath.EndsWith(".razor") && !context.Tree.FilePath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
        return;

    var sourceText = context.Tree.GetText();
    var lines = sourceText.Lines;

    var zz = CreateDiagnostic(
        Location.Create(context.Tree, context.Tree.GetText().Lines[0].Span));
    context.ReportDiagnostic(zz);
}

CreateDiagnostic is simply a warapper over stock Diagnostic.Create.
The aim is to verify that diagnostics are being raised, but that never happens. My analyzers csproj looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable> 
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
    <NoWarn>RS2008</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="6.0.35" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.11.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.11.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- This ensures the library will be packaged as an analyzer -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I've looked into dotnet soruce and found an analyzer that should apply to razor here. It looks similar, however I cannot find other examples (and I know for a fact that there are many razor analyzers, since I've seen them in action in Blazor) which makes me think that maybe due to razor pre-compiling roslyn analyzers may not be fully supported. If that's the case, how are diagnostic provided for it?

From the perspective of a Roslyn analyzer, the Razor file isn't a syntax tree but rather an "additional file" exposed through RegisterAdditionalFileAction (or similar methods.)
